# Solving $x-8 = x^{\log_{10}(2)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve the equation
$$x-8 = x^{\log_{10}(2)}$$

This is what I managed to do so far.

[image]

It is also pretty easy to find out that $x=10$ is a solution and that there are no more than 2 solutions (because $x^{\log_{10}(2)}$ is concave and $x-8$ is a line).

Comment: if lg is base 10 logarithm function, why do you take logarithm base 2 ?

Comment: What is $\lg$?  $\log_2 $?

Comment: @JeanMarie because I can use the formula for changing bases afterwards

Comment: In the end, the equation can be turned into $x=2^x +8$ ...

Comment: Comparing the RHS of your third and 4th equation : you consider that $lg(2)=1$...

Comment: @JeanMarie $x=10$ is a solution since $10^{\log_{10}2} = 2 =10-8$.

Comment: @icecream_sandwich07 My bad, you are right.

Comment: @Matti P. No, I made the same error as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to "see" the only solution:

- $\lg 2 = \frac{\log_2 2}{\log_2 10} = \frac{1}{\log_2 10}$
- $x^{\lg 2} = 2^{\log_2 x}$

So, the equation becomes
$$x-8 = x^{\lg(2)} \Leftrightarrow x - 2^{\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 10}} = 8$$

This equation has obviously the solution $x=10$.

The uniqueness follows (as already mentioned in other solution) from considering the monotonicity of $x - 2^{\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 10}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=x-x^k-8$$ where $k=\log_{10}(2) <1$ also implies that we work with $x \geq 0$.

Compute the derivatives
$$f'x)=1-k\, x^{k-1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=-k(k-1)\,x^{k-2}$$

The first derivative cancels only once at
$$x_*=\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k-1}}$$ and, since $k < 1$, by the second derivative test, this point corresponds to a minimum since $f''(x)> \,\, \forall k <1$. For $x >x_*$, $f'(x) >0$. Since, we also have $f(0)=-8$, there is only one root to the equation for any $k <1$.

I give you below the solution for various $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 &  9.11684 \\
 0.10 &  9.24914 \\
 0.15 &  9.39948 \\
 0.20 &  9.57106 \\
 0.25 &  9.76787 \\
 0.30 &  9.99496 \\
 0.35 &  10.2588 \\
 0.40 &  10.5680 \\
 0.45 &  10.9339 \\
 0.50 &  11.3723 \\
 0.55 &  11.9053 \\
 0.60 &  12.5658 \\
 0.65 &  13.4038 \\
 0.70 &  14.5010 \\
 0.75 &  16.0000 \\
 0.80 &  18.1769 \\
 0.85 &  21.6504 \\
 0.90 &  28.1834 \\
 0.95 &  45.9336
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$x=10$ is the solution since
$$
10^{\lg 2}=2=10-8
$$
To prove that there are no other solutions just plot left and right functions

Comment: Plotting functions will not "prove" something, strictly speaking...

Comment: well..yes..but in the case the right and left functions are very simple

Comment: Thus, you have to find an analysis argument like that given by @icecream_sandwich07

Answer (score 0):

$x =10$ is the only solution. Let $f(x) = x - 8 - x^{\lg2}, x\geq0$, then $f'(x)=1-\lg 2 x^{\lg 2 -1}$ and $f''(x) =  (\lg2-(\lg 2)^2  )x^{\lg 2 -2}$ which is always non-negative for all $x\geq0$. Hence, $f'(x)$ is an increasing function.

Suppose $f(x)$ has more than $1$ root, we can denote each root by $x^*_i,\ i=1,2,\dots,n$. Note that $x^*_{i+1}>x^*_i>0$. Then since $f(x^*_i)=0$, we must have $x^*_i-8={x^*_i}^{\lg2}$ for each $i$. Then $f'(x^*_i)=1-\lg2+\lg2(\frac{8}{x^*_i})>0$. This means that at each root of $f(x)$, the derivative has to be postiive.

Now we know $f(0) = -8 <0$, and $f$ is continuous on $x\geq0$.

We also know $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f'(x)=-\infty$ and $f'(x)$ is continuous on $x>0$, and $f'(x)$ is increasing.

Hence, $f'(x^*_1)>0$. For any $x>x^*_1$, $f'(x)\geq f'(x^*_1)>0$. If $f(x^*_2)=0$, by Rolle's thm, $f'(x)=0$ for some $x\in(x^*_1,x^*_2)$. but this is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry,  but $f'(x)=0$ at $x=\left(\frac{\log (2)}{\log (10)}\right)^{\frac{\log (10)}{\log (5)}}\approx 0.1795$  and $f'(0) \neq 1$ but $-\infty$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I fully agree with you, Claude. The error made by icecream_sandwich07 (that I could have done as well) is in the expression $f'(x)=1-\lg 2 x^{\lg 2 -1}$ : he hasn't seen that the exponent $log_{10}2-1$ is negative.

Comment: Crap. I fixed the proof now. @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for pointing out the mistake!